# jQuery clone() function does not copy value

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have the opposite problem about clone. I have a form and want to clone a row (2 rows exactly). I can clone the divs and inputs but none of the values can be cloned.

I made a lot of search here and on Google but don't find solution. I read through the API of jQuery clone, but it says the default behavior is to copy the input fields with values.

```js
//define template
var template = $('#termekek .row:first').clone();
//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;
//add new section        
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {
  //increment
  sectionsCount++;
  //loop through each input
  var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

    //set id to store the updated section number
    var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;
    //update for label
    $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);
    //update id
    this.id = newId;
    //set a top border to separate sections
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css({
      "border-top-color": "#f2f2f2",
      "border-top-width": "10px",
      "border-top-style": "solid",
      "padding-top": "10px"
    });
  }).end()            
  //inject new section
  .appendTo('#termekek');
  //            find('input.date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});           
  return false;

});

//remove section
$('#termekek').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  //fade out section
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
    //remove parent element (main section)
    $(this).parent().parent().empty();
    return false;
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row"><!-- Termék adatok -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="card-box">    
        <h4 class="m-t-0 m-b-30">Why not clone the value?</h4>
        <div id="termekek">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="row">                                
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="supplier">Select 1:</label>                                                                                          
                    <select class="form-control select2 orderSupplier" id="supplier" name="supplier[]">
                      <option value="Opt 1">Option 1</option>
                      <option value="Opt 2">Option 2</option>
                      <option value="Opt 3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">                                            
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="productType">Select 2:</label>
                    <select class="form-control orderProductType" name="productType[]">
                      <option value="Opt 1">Opt 1</option>
                      <option value="Opt 2">Opt 2</option>
                      <option value="Opt 3">Opt 3</option>
                      <option value="Opt 4">Opt 4</option>
                    </select>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="productName">Select 3:</label>                                            
                    <select class="form-control select2 orderProductName" id="productName" name="productName[]">
                      <option value="Opt 1">Option 1</option>
                      <option value="Opt 2">Option 2</option>
                      <option value="Opt 3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>                                        
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-1">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Quantity:</label>                                            
                  <input class="form-control orderQuantity" type="text" name="quantity[]">                                            
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-3">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Date 1:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control orderDeliveryDate" type="date" name="deliveryDate[]" id="deliveryDate">
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>                                    
              </div><!-- end col -->
            </div> <!-- end row -->

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Input text:</label>                                            
                  <input class="form-control orderCarrier" type="text" name="carrier[]">                                            
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Date 2:</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control orderArrivalDate" type="date" name="arrivalDate[]" id="arrivalDate">
                    <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>                                    
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2 col-xl-offset-1">                                       
                <div class="form-group">                                            
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="deliveryMethod">Select 4:</label>
                    <select class="form-control orderDeliveryMethod" name="deliveryMethod[]">
                      <option value="Opt 1">Option 1</option>
                      <option value="Opt 2">Option 2</option>
                      <option value="Opt 3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-1" align="center">                                       
                <div class="form-group checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-single">
                  <p style="font-weight: 500; display: inline-block; padding: 0.375rem 1rem 0.375rem 0; margin-bottom: 0;">Checkbox</p>
                  <!--<div class="switchery">-->
                  <input type="hidden" name="ekaer[]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" onclick="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value" id="ekaer">
                  <label class="form-control-label" for="ekaer" style="display: hidden;"></label>
                  <!--</div>-->                                            
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-2">                                       
                <div class="form-group">                                            
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="status">Another select</label>
                    <select class="form-control order_status" name="status[]">
                      <option value="Opt 1">Option 1</option>
                      <option value="Opt 2">Option 2</option>
                      <option value="Opt 3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div><!-- end col -->
              
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-1">
                <button type="button" name="remove" id="remove" class="btn btn-secondary active remove">-</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- end row -->     

          </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end #termekek --> 
        <div align="left">
          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary addsection">+</button>
        </div>                            
      </div><!-- end card box -->
    </div><!-- end col -->
  </div><!-- end row --> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to copy always the last row and its values when cloning.

What's wrong? Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in my code, so it works now perfectly:

```
//define template
var template = $('#contacts .row:first').clone();
//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;
//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addContact', function() {
    //increment
    sectionsCount++;
    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;
        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);
        //update id
        this.id = newId;
    }).end()
    //inject new section
    .appendTo('#contacts');
    return false;
});
//remove section
$('#contacts').on('click', '.removeContact', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```